# Python numpy interpolation gives wrong output/value

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I want to interpolate a value at y=60, the output I'm expecting should something in the region of 0.27

My code:

```
x = [4.75, 2.00, 0.850, 0.425, 0.250, 0.180, 0.150, 0.075]
y = [100, 94.5, 86.3, 74.1, 54.9, 38.1, 9.3, 1.7]
x.sort()
xi = np.interp(60, y, x)
```

Output:

```
4.75
```

Expected output:

```
0.27
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to sort the input arrays based on your `xp` (y in your case)

```py
import numpy as np

x = [4.75, 2.00, 0.850, 0.425, 0.250, 0.180, 0.150, 0.075]
y = [100, 94.5, 86.3, 74.1, 54.9, 38.1, 9.3, 1.7]
sort_idx = np.argsort(y)
x_sorted = np.array(x)[sort_idx]
y_sorted = np.array(y)[sort_idx]
xi = np.interp(60, y_sorted, x_sorted)
print(xi)
```

```
0.296484375
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `sort()` both lists, not only x coordinates but also y coordinates:

```
x.sort()
y.sort()
xi = np.interp(60, y, x)
print(xi)
## 0.296484375
```

Answer (score 0):

you sort your x array, but not the y array.
The documentation ([here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html)) says:

> One-dimensional linear interpolation for monotonically increasing sample points.

But you have a monotonously decreasing function.

```
x = np.array([4.75, 2.00, 0.850, 0.425, 0.250, 0.180, 0.150, 0.075])
x.sort()
y = np.array([100, 94.5, 86.3, 74.1, 54.9, 38.1, 9.3, 1.7])
y.sort()
xi = np.interp(60, y, x)
print(xi)
```

returns

```
0.296484375
```